# Monkey patching + autoreload of patch within Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to create a monkey patch which would be auto reloaded every time I change the patch.

I was only able create a patch within `/initialisers/` folder but initialisers are run only once.

How to do it properly?

Preblem: files which should be autoloaded should never be required. But if you want to apply a patch you have to require the file. Or am I wrong?

Comment: You mean for development only right?

Comment: Exactly! (I need some fake responses in dev only mode)